# How can I know the numeric values of the 9 TRUE values in this vector. Is there a function for it?

Tags: r

```
XOX <- Y$Wife == Y$Husband 
table(XOX)
XOX
FALSE 991
TRUE  9
```

Comment: You are looking for `Y$Wife[Y$Wife == Y$Husband]`?

Comment: Do you need the total number of cases where Y$Wife==Y$Husband?
try `sum(Y$Wife==Y$Husband)`

Comment: @HasanBhagat yeah thats the next step, thank you.

Comment: The numeric values of the indices are `which(Y$Wife == Y$Husband)`.